# Iterating Through NSIndexSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

If you have an NSArray object named anArray and an NSIndexSet object named anIndexSet, you can iterate forward through an index set as shown in below.

Excerpt, [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010165-SW4):

```
NSArray *anArray = [NSArray array];
NSIndexSet *anIndexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:3];
NSUInteger index = [anIndexSet firstIndex];

while(index != NSNotFound) {
      NSLog(@" %@",[anArray objectAtIndex:index]);
      index = [anIndexSet indexGreaterThanIndex:index];
}
```

Why terminating NSRangeException in the above scenario?

Comment: Because your array is empty. There is no object at index 3.

Comment: I get the same error when I start anArray as follows!

NSArray *anArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:anIndexSet];

Comment: Of course because that only adds one object to the array. So there is still nothing at index 3. To access index 3 you need at least four objects in the array.

Comment: In fact, I think the while() condition of the problem. arrayWithObject: if index is beyond the end of the array, an NSRangeException is raised. Also create the array with an equal number with the set gives the same error!

Comment: You seem confused about arrays. You need to actually add objects to the array. Then your index set should reference indexes that are actually valid for the number of objects in the array. Creating the array with just the index set as the only object in the array is not at all what you want to do.

Comment: index sets to store indexes into an NSArray

Answer (score 1):

I think this example describes the situation better. Also, not used an empty array as you say. Thanks so much rmaddy!!!

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"K",@"G",@"G",@"E",@"R",@"G",@"E",@"G",@"G",@"M", nil];

NSIndexSet *anIndexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [mutableArray count])];

NSUInteger index = [anIndexSet lastIndex];

while (index != NSNotFound) {
    if ([[mutableArray objectAtIndex:index] isEqualToString:@"G"]) {
        [mutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
    index = [anIndexSet indexLessThanIndex:index];
}
NSLog(@" %@", mutableArray);
```

Comment: Why are you using an index set to simply iterate through the objects of an array like this? It's completely unnecessary. Just use a simple `for` loop. No need for `NSIndexSet` in this case. Even better. Get rid of all of the code other than the array and add a single line: `[mutableArray removeObject:@"G"];`. That will remove all of the `@"G"` values from the array. No need for index sets or any loop.

Comment: Yes unnecessary in this scenario, but my priority was to understand the work with the index set. Do you think I did wrong?